# Working of Auth0 with Zuul and Eureka client

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have 5 services:

1. Zuul service
2. Auth service
3. Discovery Service
   other two are resource services

I do not understand **how the validation of token takes place**.

I understand the following:

1. Resource service and Auth will be going to register in Discovery Service
2. Zuul Service will act as a gateway service

For the 1st request

> UI (will call) --> Zuul service (will call) --> Auth service = will return token

For the 2nd request

> UI (having token inside Header)-->Zuul service -->Auth service(to
> validate token) --> Resource service = Return to UI

**or**

> UI (having token inside Header)-->Zuul service --> Resource service = Return to UI

I want to know **which flow is right**. If the 2nd is right then how does token validation take place?